# python3でのエクセルデータ読み書き

Tags: python3, excel

python 初心者で 根本的なことをあまり理解できてませんが、お教えください。

エクセルVBAに限界を感じて、python3でのエクセルデータ読み書きにトライしてるのですが
xlrd、xlwt　を見よう見まねで記述しても・・・・うまく出来ず。

例えば、エクセル（指定ファイル、指定シート）の　
1行目からA列の値（読み）を順次読んで、
B列に値を出力（書き）する場合は、どのように記述すれば良いのでしょうか？

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import xlrd
import xlwt

book = xlrd.open_workbook('j.xls') 
sheet_1 = book.sheet_by_index(0)

for row in range(sheet_1.nrows):
    if sheet_1.cell(row, 1).value >= 10 :
        sheet_1.write(row, 2, '10以上')
    else
        sheet_1.write(row, 2, '10未満')
```

Comment: 編集でコードブロックを追加したのですが、インデントが投稿者さんの意図しないものになっていると思います。文字数の制限で自分では再編集できないので、調整をお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

さしあたって下記のように書き換えれば、要望として出されている課題は達成できそうです。

おそらく質問の意図は「手軽かつ柔軟に既存のシートを上書きしたい」ということだと思いますが、pythonからのExcel出力は詳しくないので、有効なアドバイスを追記することができません。

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import xlrd
import xlwt
#エクセル読込
reader = xlrd.open_workbook('j.xls') 
r_sheet = reader.sheet_by_index(0)
#書込用シート作成
writer = xlwt.Workbook()
w_sheet = writer.add_sheet(r_sheet.name) #上書き保存するため、読込シートと同名
for row in range(r_sheet.nrows):
    w_sheet.write(row, 0, r_sheet.cell(row, 0).value) #既存の値をコピー
    if r_sheet.cell(row, 0).value >= 10:
        w_sheet.write(row, 1, '10以上')
    else:
        w_sheet.write(row, 1, '10未満')
writer.save('j.xls') #上書き保存
```